# Bad Sector: Do I need to replace my hard disk?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, file-corruption, bad-sectors

Recently my computer started to behave strangely. It hangs or stops responding suddenly, some known and unknown programs (system applications I think, and others too) starts shutting down all of a sudden and sometimes fails to start when I boot the computer, blue screen appears (happened twice), etc.

I performed a Windows' (Windows 7 ultimate) default 'Fix file system error' and 'bad sector' scanning and recovery. It found some corrupt files and fixed it and my computer was okay for a while. But the same problem started again after a while and I had to perform the 'Fix file system error' and 'bad sector' scanning and recovery again. This scan found the following errors:--

```
CHKDSK is verifying file data (stage 4 of 5)...
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 59731 of name \hiberfil.sys.
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 63808 of name \windows\system32\config\RegBack\SYSTEM.
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 112874 of name \PROGRA~2\Dropbox\update\download\{cc460~1\60.4.107\DROPBO~1.EXE.
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 139794 of name \users\..\DOWNLO~1\INTELD~1\WIN64_~1.EXE.
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 145567 of name \Search\Data\APPLIC~1\Windows\Projects\SYSTEM~1\Indexer\CiFiles\0001002D.Ci.
183536 files processed
File data verification completed.
```

My questions are:
What does all this mean? Why did it happen? Is this problem going to recur, persist, spread/deteriorate? What is the permanent/lasting solution? Do I need to replace my hard disk now? I have important files in it, which I don't want to lose!

Comment: It's likely to deteriorate. You should do backups ASAP.

Comment: Please download crystaldiskinfo and post a screenshot of the program with the tab of the disk in question open

Comment: If the files are important, they should be backed up already; only unimportant files are not backed up.

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: Back up your data immediately. Did you actually find any bad sectors, or just the corrupted clusters that you posted? How are you shutting down your computer?

Comment: Try to backup your data at first, then refer the link https://windowsreport.com/bad-sectors-windows-8/ to fix bad sectors. If it fails we could consider to replace it.

Comment: This could be just recurring file corruption that has nothing to do with a failing hard drive.  For example, if your system hangs and you hold the power button to power down, it can leave things corrupted; there might be some underlying problem or practice that keeps leaving the drive with corrupted files.  Or, it could be a failing hard drive.  Run the SMART check.  Review your recent history of problems and things you might have done that could explain the corruption.  (cont'd)

Comment: Look for patterns, like a particular application you use and then tend to find corruption the next time you turn it on.  If it's an old drive, say 7+ years old, you might want to replace it even if you aren't sure it's failing.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a replacement hard drive.  Either completely stop using the old HD, or only use it for unimportant data.  If it were me, I would make a completely clean new OS install on the new HD, and copy important info over afterward.

Google researchers published a study on hard drive failure rates a few years ago : https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/disk_failures.pdf .  One of the take aways was that, when a single symptom of physical hard drive failure shows up, problems accumulate more quickly after that.  That is based off SMART metrics.

Since the Question didn't mention a cause or correlating outside event (thunderstorm, accidental disconnect, etc), it may be that the original HD has reached the end of its life.